# Decryption code from the image

Tags: image, encryption, encoding, decoding

I have two images: the [one](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/9325/one12s.jpg) and the [two](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2747/two637.jpg).

How do I decode it?

Comment: Follow the instructions in `cluel.png` and copy the pixels from `questionq.png` to a new 400x400 image in the manner described. Considering that each pixel is covered exactly once, you should be able to derive an integer formula for the spiral and serpentine access.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that. can anyone help?

Comment: unfortunately on SO we can't give away answers to interview questions. Let's consider two sub-questions. First, which **language** do you plan to use, that will open an PNG file and allow you to access each pixel at each `(x,y)` coordinates? Second, how to **calculate** the `(x,y)` coordinates according to the __spiral__ and __linear serpentine__ rules shown in the clue image? SO will answer the first question but you must work on the second question by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started in the right direction, its un-tested and may contain syntax errors but should work.

```
<?PHP
  $out = imagecreatetruecolor(400,400);
  $in  = imagecreatefrompng('questionq.png');

  $dest_x   = 0;
  $dest_y   = 0;
  $dest_dir = 0;

  function setImagePixel($color) {
    global $out, $dest_x; $dest_y, $dest_dir;
    imagesetpixel($out, $dest_x, $dest_y, $color);
    if ($dest_dir == 0) {
      if (++$dest_x == 399) {
        ++dest_y;
        $dest_dir = 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (--$dest_x == 0) {
        ++dest_y;
        $dest_dir = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  for($count = 400; $count > 0; --$count) {      
    $offset = 400 - $count;
    for($x = $offset; $x < $count    ; ++$x) setImagePixel(imagecolorat($in, $x     , $offset));
    for($y = $offset; $y < $count    ; ++$y) setImagePixel(imagecolorat($in, $count , $y     ));
    for($x = $count; $x > $offset    ; --$x) setImagePixel(imagecolorat($in, $x     , $count ));
    for($y = $count; $y > $offset + 1; --$y) setImagePixel(imagecolorat($in, $offset, $y     ));
  }

  imagepng($out, 'decoded.png');
?>
```

Comment: very thanks for reply, but this isn't working good. i have mass notice: Notice: imagecolorat() [function.imagecolorat]: 400,0 is out of bounds in localhost\image.php on line 28 . generated: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9935/decoded.png but nothing can be read from this

Comment: Like I said, its un-tested, may need some tweaking, try change 400 to 399 everywhere, as images are zero based like arrays, 0-399, not 1-400.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to this puzzle will lead you to a Google Spreadsheet document. Which one that is is the next puzzle.

A little weird is that the decoded image is not easily readable, you first have to apply a "remove each second line" filter on it. Fortunately GIMP comes with such a filter built-in.

Comment: when writing to the destination image, every other line is written in opposite direction.

Comment: Yes, I know, I did that. But still the text is not clearly readable. I also tried both, writing the pixels bidirectionally and unidirectionally.

Comment: @selectready: I think I have given enough hints.

Comment: @Roland: you're right. I ended up (1) using bidirectional, and (2) having to shift every other rows by a variable amounts (and save image each time) so that I can unscramble and see various parts of the string (one part at a time).

Comment: @selectready: I doubt there's any "off the shelf" software that can do it (besides @Roland's GIMP suggestion). It certainly requires programming. I think this test is very well designed.

Comment: In the end I just wrote the pixels unidirectionally to an image with 799x400 pixels. That made it easily readable, although it was displayed twice: On the left side the text was how I expected it, on the right side it was mirrored, with a much larger margin to the right. Anyway, now I have built a simple image processing "framework" in Java and can easily produce such images myself.

Comment: so what the text is encoded there? i can't deal with this

Comment: Maybe 101studio.pl is looking for people who can solve this puzzle themselves. You haven't even told us what you tried up to now, or which programming languages you are fluent with. So how are we supposed to help you in a *useful* way? Just telling you the answer isn't it.